# Notification from the db instead of polling. Is it possible?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-2008

Hy guys,

to monitor a specified table on db I'm polling this one every few milliseconds (10-20 ms).

Is there any chance to have a notification (avoiding SqlDependency, that in my scenario is too slow) instead polling?

Do you have any idea?

My scenario is .net + Sql Server 2008

Thanks!

Comment: @Blam I know, and this is the reason why I want to change my approach

Comment: Just wanted to validate.  SqlChangeMonitor class may not be that fast.  Where is the update to the data coming from and do you have control of database server.  E.G. could you add stored procedure, trigger, clr?

Comment: That gives a lot more options.  But still you did not answer a question.  Where is the update coming from and do you have control of that application?

Comment: @Blam: The update coming from a low level system, and I have the control of the insert statement of this application, and I have too the complete control of the Sql Server used to exchange data

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, using a CLR stored procedure that will call a WCF/or a webservice. It is not something very difficult to do.

This needs practically 2 steps.

1. The modification of data. 
   After you modified the data you have to send the data to the clr stored procedure. The easiest way is to write it into one ore more temporary tables.
2. The clr stored procedure. 
   The clr store procedure will connect to the db with

   "context connection=true"

so that you will have access to the stored procedures that you need. After loading the data you send it to a server (WCF/webservice). In the CLR you just need to add the service references that you need. Also on the server you will have to register some dlls for the server to use:

```
system.web
smdiagnostics
system.runtime.serialization
system.identitymodel
system.identitymodel.selectors
system.messagng
system.transactions.bridge
system.servicemodel
```

Everything else is plain .NET code to call a WCF/Web service.
This approach is very fast and very reliable.

Comment: Feasible, but I'd like to have something more event oriented, if possible

Comment: More event oriented ? What do you mean ? This is something I used when I needed instant notification for changes in the database. The changes were done to up to 30 tables, and the application was notified with everything it happened. Also, in that case multiple services were notified, depending on the data changed .. I do not know of any other faster notification method ..

Comment: As a side note, it is up to you how complex this can be. This is only a frame to start with. I had threaded notifications with queues for each service to insure the right order of the messages, in case that this notifications come so fast (10-20ms is very fast)

Comment: It is not so complex. I have only one source of messages and only one target: they simply have to communicate fast and going through sql server

Comment: This is as fast as your network is. And if it is only a notification, you do not need to actually store data in the temp tables, and that will make it even faster. I have notifications in about 2ms.

Comment: I need notification, and as the data is there I can fast read it.
Should be good if I could have notification and data togheter.
Do you think is possible?

Comment: Yes .. it is .. practically what I wrote, I wrote starting from that assumption, that you need to be notified along with the data that is changed.

Answer (score 1):

To get onChange event notification in SQL, you can use the [Query Notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/features/working-with-query-notifications?view=sql-server-ver15) feature which is built on Server Broker.

Alternatives are:

1. DB trigger
2. SignalR
3. Change Data Capture
4. Change Tracking

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [SqlChangeMonitor class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.sqlchangemonitor.aspx),  but that wraps SqlDependency in cached data scenarios.  Your question is a little vague on why you want to do this, though.

Comment: I need this polling to know as fast as possible if a data is stored on db to redirect this message to another system. And in my scenario I must be fast

Answer (score 0):

Can the calling application be changed to say write to a [queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue) instead?

If not I guess a trigger on the database which calls a [CLR Stored Procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)? That could fire off any kind of event required.

Comment: Yes, I could also change application. But what do you mean with queue? And once I have the message in this queue, how to notify my application that a new data is ready to be fetched?

Answer (score 0):

I see you say you need **notifications** (and `SqlDependency` is available for that), but maybe you don't need instant notifications, and efficiently reading the changes periodically will do the task. If so, go google `Change Data Capture`, and `Change Tracking`.

Comment: Unfortunately I need instant (or almost istant, I can "wait" no more than a dozen of ms)